# Open Run Configuration... dialog in a eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jface

I want to create a button that start "Run Configuration..." dialog. How can i do this? I have seen with Spy that Active shell class is LaunchConfigurationsDialog but i don't know how use this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LaunchConfigurationsDialog` is in an internal package so should not be used directly.

The `DebugUIPlugin` provides this method to open this dialog:

```
int openLaunchConfigurationsDialog(Shell shell, IStructuredSelection selection, String groupIdentifier, boolean setDefaults)
```

Javadoc:

```
Opens the LaunchConfigurationsDialog on the given selection for the given group. A status can be provided or null and the dialog can initialize the given ILaunchConfiguration to its defaults when opening as well - as long as the specified configuration is an ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy.

Parameters:
shell the shell to open the dialog on
selection the non-null selection to show when the dialog opens
groupIdentifier the identifier of the launch group to open the dialog on
setDefaults if the default values should be set on the opened configuration - if there is one
Returns:
the return code from the dialog.open() call
```

but `DebugUIPlugin` is also in an internal package.

The command id for the 'Run Configurations' menu is `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.OpenRunConfigurations` so you can execute that command using something like:

```
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.OpenRunConfigurations", null);
```

Comment: I use this code: 
`DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialog(getShell(), DebugUITools.getLastLaunch(IDebugUIConstants.ID_RUN_LAUNCH_GROUP ), IDebugUIConstants.ID_RUN_LAUNCH_GROUP ,  null);`
But it show only a dialog with a single launch configuration. I need to show exactly what is shown when i click on Run->Run Configurations... command.

Comment: Actually `DebugUIPlugin` is also in an internal package so this is not supposed to be used either.

Comment: Added how to invoke the command for the menu item to the answer.

Comment: I have used `IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.OpenRunConfigurations", null);` into a button's selection listener but there is an error: `The method getSite() is undefined for the type new SelectionListener(){}` . How can i solve?

Comment: `getSite()` method is defined in a view or editor part, you need to pass it to your code.

Comment: My button is defined in a `WizardPage`. Is it possible to use `getSite()` yet?

Comment: There is also `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService()`

Comment: I have tried:
`IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
try {  handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.OpenRunConfigurations", null);
....`
but don't work.

Comment: I have done! 
`IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getService(IHandlerService.class);  handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.OpenRunConfigurations", null);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is to use `org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction`
and you can specify the group in the constructor `IDebugUIConstants.ID_RUN_LAUNCH_GROUP`
For your information, you can also create your own group and only display this group.